# how to make icons and buttons bigger in ionic 2

Tags: cordova, typescript, icons, ionic2

How can make `button` and `icon` size bigger in fallowing code:

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-header>
    Explore Nearby
  </ion-card-header>

  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="cart" item-left></ion-icon>
      Shopping
    </button>

    <button ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="medical" item-left></ion-icon>
      Hospital
    </button>

    <button ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="cafe" item-left></ion-icon>
      Cafe
    </button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

#### Icons

`ion-icon`s are font icons so they can be edited the following Sass/CSS as they are essentially text:

```
    ion-icon {
        font-size: 20px; //Preferred size here
    }
```

#### Buttons

As for the `button` ionic has some inbuilt classes to affect size.  For example:

```
   <button ion-button large>Large</button>

   <button ion-button>Default</button>

   <button ion-button small>Small</button>
```

You can also update the default Sass variable of `$button-round-padding` in your `src/theme/variables.scss` file, to the size that you would like.  More on buttons can be found [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/button/Button/)

Answer (score 12):

In my Ionic 4 apps I adopted the following approach. In the *.scss file:

```
ion-icon { zoom: 1.5 }
```

Of course, zoom value depend on your needs.
Hope this help someone. o/

Comment: awesome solution

Answer (score 5):

Even for Icon we can use large and small to the ion-icon tag. This is how I had used

`<ion-icon name="arrow-forward" item-end small></ion-icon>`

Answer (score 4):

To specify the icon size, you can use the **size** attribute for pre-defined font sizes. Example is given below:

```
<ion-icon size="small"></ion-icon>
<ion-icon size="large"></ion-icon>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add this following code :

ion-icon {font-size: 3rem;}